# App Update rejected Will previous version be taken down?

Tags: iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

If I push an app update to the app store, but choose "I will release new version" when submitting. If my update is rejected for some reason, is the current version already approved going to be taken out of the store?

Anyone had experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one app where an update was rejected over a year ago.  I haven't resubmitted the update yet and the original is still selling in the app store.

Comment: Did you say you would release it or they should automatically release it?

Comment: I believe it was "release immediately" but I don't think that will make a difference.  Apple has no reason to remove an approved app from the store.

Answer (score 1):

I've got no experience with this exact situation, but I have submitted updates and then invalidated them myself. The original is unaffected until the new version is approved - if it gets rejected, they would just expect you to send a corrected version instead.

The only reason I could see Apple pulling the original would be if they discovered something pretty nasty in the update and decided to check the original as well in case they'd missed it, but that is total speculation.